# How to make a SizedBox shrink as much as possible when showing a bottom sheet?

Tags: flutter, dart

As the main content for a bottom sheet I am returning a `SizedBox` with a column and some children inside. However, when showing the bottom sheet, the height of the `SizedBox` is set to be of fixed value (half the height of the screen by default if a height is not specified) instead of allowing the `SizedBox` to shrink as much as possible to fit its content. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `mainAxisSize` property of the `Column` widget to `MainAxisSize.min` and it will adjust its height to fit the content. Example:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: const Text('Screen'),
  ),
  bottomSheet: Container(
    color: Colors.greenAccent,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: const Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Text('This is your minimal bottom sheet.'),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text('It adjusts it\'s height to fit it\'s content ...'),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Text('...thanks to the MainAxisSize.min property'),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]